# String replace according to position?

Tags: java, string, replace

I have this String 11101011.I want to replace last three char '011' with 101.is there any function of String in java to do so?

Answer (score 2):

Use `string.replaceAll` function.

```
string.replaceAll(".{3}$", "101");
```

`.{3}` matches exactly three characters and `$` asserts that the match must be followed by an end of the line.

**Example:**

```
String name = "11101011";
String result = name.replaceAll(".{3}$", "101");
System.out.println(result);
```

Output:

```
11101101
```

Answer (score 2):

Using String replace and regular expressions for this task seems like breaking butterflies on a wheel - just cut the last three characters off and append the new suffix (ultimately verbose solution):

```
final String oldString = "11101011";
final String oldSuffix = oldString.substring(5);
final String reducedOldString = oldString.substring(0, oldString.length() - oldSuffix.length());

final String newSuffix = "101";
final String newString = reducedOldString.concat(newSuffix);

System.out.println("newString = " + newString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)) method of String class

```
String s="11101011";
System.out.println(s.replace("011","101"));
```

**O/P:**
11101101

Comment: This would replace any occurrence of `"011"` and not just the last one. If OP uses a different String, this could would fail.

Comment: Yes, it is not generic solution but the solution for OP's question